# How can I subtract two dates and get a new date converted in minutes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I need to subtract two dates, date1 and date2(current date), using Linq expressions. I need to verify if the subtraction between these two date isn't above 12 hours.  I only want to get the data that has less than 12 hours. The code bellow is the code of my controller (GET), right now I'm subtracting the two dates and converting the result in minutes. I'm not sure if that's the right approach.

```
var date2 = DateTime.Now;
var model= _context.Model.Where(e => (e.Prop1== "hello world"  && (e.date1 - date2).Minutes <= 12 * 60));
```

Right know it shows all the data that I have on my database.

Comment: use `TimeSpan.TotalHours` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subtract two `DateTime` the result is a `TimeSpan`

Use [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan_TotalHours) property, which simplifies to

```
... (e.date1 - date2).TotalHours <= 12) ...
```

based on the desired behavior

Comment: Does this also work if I want to be exact to the minute? For example, the data still appears if it's been in the database for 11 hours and 59 seconds?

Comment: @TeresaAlves Yes. TotalHours will include a fraction of the time duration. If you want minutes you can use `TotalMinutes` then